# How to pass typescript property to bootstrap related jQuery function in Angular Application

Tags: angular, typescript

`this.addRoleFormGroup.dirty;`  //want to pass this property to jQuery `on("hide.bs.modal", function())`

```
this.addRoleFormGroup.dirty;
    $("#addRoleModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
      alert('The modal is about to be hidden.');
      $('#addRoleModal').modal('show');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arrow function for your JQuery event handler. That way the outer `this` will be accessible from within the callback:

```
$("#addRoleModal").on("hide.bs.modal", () => {
    console.log(this.addRoleFormGroup.dirty);
    $('#addRoleModal').modal('show');
});
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for more information.